# Heroku has temporarily disabled this feature, please try again shortly

Tags: heroku

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema?

Eu executar esse comando `heroku apps:create wb-arm-wladimir`

E gerou esse erro:

```
C:\Users\Wladimir\Documents\teste>heroku apps:create laravel-vue-axios
Creating laravel-vue-axios... !
 !    Heroku has temporarily disabled this feature, please try again shortly. See https://status.heroku.com for current
 !    Heroku platform status.

C:\Users\Wladimir\Documents\teste>
```

Comment: Segundo o link http://status.heroku.com, eles tiveram um incidente e desabilitaram builds para todos os apps. https://status.heroku.com/incidents/1334

Comment: está aparecendo trolagem rs

Comment: conhece algum servidor que seja gratis?

Comment: Grátis eu não conheço, só aquelas que você pode começar grátis, em que geralmente te dão uns créditos iniciais. Acabei de acessar o http://status.heroku.com e já normalizaram a situação.